# No module named 'statsmodels.genmod.penalties'

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have installed `statsmodels` library in Jupyter Notebook.
Now when i try to execute my code it says there is no module named `statsmodels.genmod.penalties`.

I think i am importing `L1` penalty in the wrong way. But I coudn't the correct implementation either.

Below is the code i am struggling with,

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.genmod.families import links 
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model import GLM 
from statsmodels.genmod.cov_struct import CovStruct 
from statsmodels.genmod.families.family import Binomial, NegativeBinomial, Gamma, Gaussian, InverseGaussian, Poisson, Tweedie 
from statsmodels.genmod.families.varfuncs import Binomial as Binomial_VarFunc 
from statsmodels.genmod.families.links import Logit 
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model import *
from statsmodels.genmod.penalties import L1

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

n = np.random.randint(0,2000)

#sample size
p = 20

#no. of variables
sigma = np.full((p,p), 0.5)

# True covariance matrix
np.fill_diagonal(sigma, 1)

X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean = np.zeros(p), cov = sigma, size = n)

# generate mutlivariate normal data
y = (np.random.rand(n) < 0.5).astype(int)

X = sm.add_constant(X)

penalty = sm.penalties.L1(alpha = 0.1) # use L1 penalty with alpha parameter
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 23
     19 y = (np.random.rand(n) < 0.5).astype(int)
     21 X = sm.add_constant(X)
---> 23 penalty = sm.penalties.L1(alpha = 0.1) # use L1 penalty with alpha parameter
     25 model = sm.GLM(y, X, family = sm.families.Binomial(link = sm.families.links.logit), penalized = True, penalty = penalty)
     27 result = model.fit()
AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.api' has no attribute 'penalties'
```

and if I removed `sm` from `sm.penalties.L1` then I get this error.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 23
     19 y = (np.random.rand(n) < 0.5).astype(int)
     21 X = sm.add_constant(X)
---> 23 penalty = penalties.L1(alpha = 0.1) # use L1 penalty with alpha parameter
     25 model = sm.GLM(y, X, family = sm.families.Binomial(link = sm.families.links.logit), penalized = True, penalty = penalty)
     27 result = model.fit()
NameError: name 'penalties' is not defined
```

Comment: I think you imported `L1` from this line `from statsmodels.genmod.penalties import L1`. Have you tried removing both `sm` and `penalties` ? And then you have `L1(alpha = 0.1)`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this; getting error already in `from statsmodels.genmod.penalties import L1` - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.genmod.penalties'`. There does not seem to be such a module in statsmodels.

Comment: I guess you want `fit_regularized` https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit_regularized.html . GLM itself does not allow specifying penalties even if penalties are correctly imported.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a small issue with how you are importing the L1 penalty module. The correct way to import it is from `statsmodels.base` rather than `statsmodels.api`. Here's the corrected import statement:

```
from statsmodels.base import penalties
```

Your code should more or less look like below. This should resolve the import issue and allow you to use the L1 penalty in your code.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.genmod.families import links 
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model import GLM 
from statsmodels.genmod.cov_struct import CovStruct 
from statsmodels.genmod.families.family import Binomial, NegativeBinomial, Gamma, Gaussian, InverseGaussian, Poisson, Tweedie 
from statsmodels.genmod.families.varfuncs import Binomial as Binomial_VarFunc 
from statsmodels.genmod.families.links import Logit 
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model import *
from statsmodels.base import penalties  # Corrected import

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

n = np.random.randint(0, 2000)

# sample size
p = 20

# no. of variables
sigma = np.full((p, p), 0.5)

# True covariance matrix
np.fill_diagonal(sigma, 1)

X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(p), cov=sigma, size=n)

# generate multivariate normal data
y = (np.random.rand(n) < 0.5).astype(int)

X = sm.add_constant(X)

penalty = penalties.L1(alpha=0.1)  # use L1 penalty with alpha parameter
model = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Binomial(link=sm.families.links.logit), penalized=True, penalty=penalty)
result = model.fit()
```

Comment: This does not work because GLM does not support penalized or penalty keyword.